# how can I add order by clause to a java entity?

Tags: java, entity, ebean

I use java and avaje ebean 2.8.1.
I want do specific query for a method.
For Example:
   select * from children where removed=false order by born_date

```
@Entity 
public class Client {
    @Id 
    private Long id; 

    @OneToMany 
    private List<Child> children; //this return all, include removed=true

    public List<Child>  getChildren(){
        return children;
    }
```

Comment: So are you asking for order or for limiting relations? o.O

Comment: both, limit and order

Comment: you should setOrderBy in your list query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [`@Where`](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/Where.html) annotation, it's still valid in 2.8.x

Comment: I don't know what you did, you even didn't show us how you selecting your objects

Comment: In this method getChildren(), I want add it a "order" clause